# Spring-Boot Data JPA findByField does not work on MySQL table REST

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, findby

I want to query in Java Spring Boot JPA for risk parameter of type enum in my Virus table:

```
public interface VirusRepository extends JpaRepository<Virus, Long> {

    List<Virus> findByRisk(@RequestParam("risk") String risk);
}
```

this is my Virus class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "virus")
@Data
public class Virus {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "mortality_rate")
    private float mortality_rate;

    @Column(name = "risk")
    private String risk;

    @Column(name = "year")
    private int year;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "treatment_id", nullable = false)
    private Treatment treatment;
}
```

My treatment table: (virus has fk-key treatment id)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "treatment")
@Data
public class Treatment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "treatment")
    private Set<Virus> viruses;
}
```

However, I do not get the desired data returned when I enter url: `http://localhost:9999/api/viruses/?risk=high`

why? is it maybe because I defined risk of type enum on my MySQL Table Virus entity?:

[image: http://localhost:9999/api/viruses/?name=SARS]

****EDIT: I just found it out myself, I forgot that the link is:**

http://localhost:9999/api/viruses/search/findByRisk?risk=high

**then I get the correct response back.****

Comment: add an answer with a complete explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what logic you are using but from my personnal experience, i have never seen sombedy put a `@RequestParam`in a `Repository interface`.
This is how i would do it :

1. You data classes are fine, nothing to note there
2. The interface for extending `JpaRepository`is not the place for your `@RequestParam`. try to do it like this :

> ```
> @Repository    
> public interface VirusRepository extends JpaRepository<Virus, Long> {  
>     List<Virus> findByRiskContainingIgnoreCase(String risk);    
> }
> ```

3. Then create an `interface` than will map all your methods :

> ```
> public interface VirusService {
>     List<Virus> findByrisk(String risk);    
> }
> ```

4. Create a service implementation class to implement all your service methods :

> ```
> @Service
> public class VirusServiceImpl implements VirusService {    
>     
>     @Autowired
>     private VirusRepository repository;   
>
>     @Override
>     public List<Virus> findByRisk(String risk) {   
>         return repository.findByRiskContainingIgnoreCase(risk);   
>     }    
> }
> ```

5. You create the `controller` that will accept your request :

> ```
> @RestController    
> @RequestMapping("/virus/")    
> public class VirusController {    
>      
>      @Autowired
>      private VirusService service;    
>
>      @GetMapping("/findByRisk")
>      public List<Virus> findByRisk(@RequestParam("risk") String risk) {    
>          return service.findByRisk(risk);   
>      }    
> }
> ```

6. Make a request to you `localhost:8080/risk/findByRisk`and it should be fine.